# A sentence from Swan's PEU using plural 'are' and not singular 'is'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, quantificational-nouns

In Swan's PEU (3rd Edition), an entry number 157 of 'discourse markers' reads...

> There ***are*** a very large number of these 'discourse markers', and it is impossible to give a complete list in a few pages.

I'm finding it difficult to understand. Why is there a plural verb *are* and not *is*? I also note that *discourse markers* are defined in quotes ('...') which means it's considered as a single entity.

> There ***are*** a very large number of 'X' out there ***does not look better to*** 
>  There ***is*** a very large number of 'X' out there

Let me quote [a quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/t/tomstoppar636116.html) here

> Despite the digital age, there **is a very large number of** venues and spaces that are looking for plays, and many of them are looking for new plays.

Also, [a result from the Google Books](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=R_NVGZRZVHoC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=%22there%20is%20a%20very%20large%20number%22&source=bl&ots=gQVkGqBhGk&sig=_2KJvcUAEpWB97DkHQXRs9Ralvs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tof0U9T_MYfGuATS2YGoCA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22there%20is%20a%20very%20large%20number%22&f=false)

> What makes the fields 'classical' is the fact that there **is very large number of** sources contributing.

What am I missing?

Comment: This reminds me of "proximity agreement". I couldn't find a good reference, but I found [this](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/proximityagreement.htm): As noted in *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language (1985)*, "Conflict between grammatical concord and attraction through proximity tends to increase with the distance between the noun phrase head of the subject and the verb."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CGEL (*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) discusses (at 3.3, p.349) situations where quantification is “expressed by means of a noun as head with an *of* PP as complement”. In these constructions terms like *a lot, lots, a great deal, plenty, oodles* and *a number* are in syntactic *form* the heads of the NPs in which they occur, but the semantic head is the ‘oblique’, the term which is the object of *of*:

> **a.** Lots of work<sup>oblique</sup> is left to be done.
>   **b.** A lot of people<sup>oblique</sup> were present.

Note that in **a** *lots* is plural, but the entire NP takes a singular verb, *is*, because its oblique, *work*, is non-count, while in **b** *a lot* is singular but the entire NP takes a plural verb, *were*, because its oblique, *people*, is plural-only.

In these cases, says CGEL, “*lot* is **number-transparent** in that it allows the number of the oblique to percolate up to determine the number of the whole NP.”

In other words, semantics trumps syntax with these “number transparent quantificational nouns”: the verb agrees with the sense rather than the form.

In your sentence, consequently, the verb correctly takes the plural because its real subject is the oblique *these 'discourse markers'*, not *a very large number*.

With many singular number-transparent nouns such as *number*, however, many people feel uncomfortable with a violation of syntactic concord. Consequently, you are just as likely to encounter a 'number-opaque' treatment. In the circumstances, neither can legitimately be labeled “incorrect”.

Note, by the way, that the phrase *a very large number* acting as a NP on its own, not quantifying an oblique, will take a singular verb:

> A small number is expressed in words; a large number is expressed in digits; a very large number is expressed in exponential notation.

Comment: What is this language coming to if we need one grammar book to understand the other...

Comment: @oerkelens lol. It's not "coming to" anything: it's exactly where it's always been. See Goold's [Grammar of English Grammars](http://books.google.com/books?id=7ZAxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA617&dq=english+gerund+possessive&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gGSJUp_BCdOl2AXgrYGICQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=english%20gerund%20possessive&f=false), 1851.... Actually, I don't know Swan, but it is spoken of very highly by users I respect; and I betcha it addresses this question somewhere.

Comment: The book seems to address the usage as you said indeed, though it might not explain the issue in depth. For those who have PEU, it's discussed in 526.2.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thanks. You're one of the users mentioned in my previous comment, and it's clear that PEU will have to be my next purchase.

Comment: @StoneyB Luckily, PEU is much cheaper than CGEL :-) Actually, Swan acknowledges both H&P 2002 and Quirk et al 1985 in the first pages of his book—he's distilled a lot of wisdom from those voluminous tomes into a much smaller pedagogical grammar.  Occasionally you might feel he's oversimplified but overall it's quite good!  And there is a little information there that isn't in either reference grammar.  If nothing else, it's worth having because it's the most popular reference for ELLs.

Comment: This pretty much makes sense, except for the bit about the "real subject". You can completely remove the supposed "real subject" and still have a sensible sentence. Interesting perspective, though.

Comment: @DCShannon In that case you have a *fused-head determiner*: a determiner (in this case a quantifier) which swallows up its head, just as you do in "{Some / Many / Three / A few } [of our students] won scholarships."

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Lucian Sava in his answer, [Google's corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+is+a+large+number%2C+there+are+a+large+number&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20large%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20large%20number%3B%2Cc0) supports that both uses are often found in standard English. It is possible to analyse them as follows:

---

> There are **[<sub>NP</sub> a very large number of these 'discourse markers']**, and it is impossible to give a complete list in a few pages.

The sentence above can be analysed as a complex noun phrase (NP):

> a very large number of these 'discourse markers'

where the NP head is *"'discourse markers'"* and *"a very large number of these"* is functioning as a determiner.

By accepting this analysis, it is possible to understand that the verb *"are"* and the NP head *"'discourse markers'"* concord in number.

---

> Despite the digital age, there is **[<sub>NP</sub> a very large number of venues and spaces that are looking for plays, and many of them are looking for new plays]**.

The use of "is" can be justified as follows. In this case, the noun phrase (NP) is a *complex phrase* with a *determiner*, a *head* and a *complement*. The head would be *"number"*, the determiner *"a very large"* and the complement *"of venues and spaces that ..."*.

By accepting that the NP head is *"number"* it is possible to understand the concord between "is" and "number".

Comment: Did you do that correctly? What about the other examples? How would you part it?

Comment: @MaulikV I've just updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: I disagree. I would say "Despite the digital age, there **are** a very large number of venues and spaces that are looking for plays, and many of them are looking for new plays." Otherwise, it should read "Despite the digital age, there **is** a very large number of venues and spaces that **is** looking for plays, and many of them **is** looking for new plays." which is obviously wrong. In my mind, "venues and spaces" makes it plural.

Comment: @CJDennis The second example sounds off because it'd make "a large number" the subject of "is looking for plays"; "to look for" is unusual with inanimate subjects.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+is+a+large+number%2C+there+are+a+large+number&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20large%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20large%20number%3B%2Cc0) both are grammatically correct, but the use of one version or another it's really dependent on whether what is being discussed is singular or plural.

In your case *these* implies plural.

Comment: But *these* is merely reintroducing the discourse markers and even if we keep plural, it should take the singular verb *is*. Check my other examples; they talk about venues and spaces and sources - all are plural