# Dangling modifier in sentence

Tags: modifiers

This sentence is said to be correct:

> Skeptical of the abilities of prophets to tell the future, a significant number of philosophers in Athens began to value reason over revealed truths.

*"Skeptical"* modifies *"number",* but *"number"* cannot be *"Skeptical."* 
*"Skeptical"* should modify *"philosophers."*

Can someone shed light on this sentence?

Comment: It's OK: *a number of* is understood to act as a quantifier rather than a noun (technically, a "quantificational noun"), so the actual subject of the head clause is *philosophers*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange! Nice first question.

Comment: @StoneyB I looked up quantificational nouns, and I'm not sure that it actually applies in this case. Maybe it's just a different way of looking at things. Would you care to elaborate, perhaps in an answer?

Comment: @DCShannon Take a look at [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31841/32), where my answer cites *CGEL*. Other common 'number-transparent quantificational nouns' that are singular in form but accept a plural oblique are *lot*, *plenty*, *rest* and *couple*.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, a *number* can indeed be skeptical.  Something like:

> A skeptical number began to value reason.

is just fine.  There's nothing wrong with this.  A valid meaning of *number* is *a few from a larger group*.

Of course, without context or previous conversation/text we'd be asking *number of what?*.  But that's explicitly stated your example, so no confusion.

Numbers as in numerals can't be skeptical, so anyone hearing/reading something like this won't be thinking that.

Answer (score 1):

### Simplify for Clarity

Let's strip this sentence down:

> Skeptical of the abilities of prophets to tell the future, a significant number of philosophers in Athens began to value reason over revealed truths.

The first clause adds meaning, but isn't essential to the core sentence.

> A significant number of philosophers in Athens began to value reason over revealed truths.

The last clause only tells us a bit more about how *much* they're valuing reason, so it's not essential.

> A significant number of philosophers in Athens began to value reason.

Significant is just an adjective, let's drop that.

> A number of philosophers in Athens began to value reason.

Who cares where these philosophers are located?

> A number of philosophers began to value reason.

"Of philosophers" is just a prepositional phrase describing what we have a number *of*.

> A number began to value reason.

This is a perfectly valid sentence. "A number" is the subject. This is one of the most common usages of the word 'number'.

### Dictionary Definitions

Some different phrasings of its definition from a few dictionaries:

Wiktionary:

> 5. Quantity

Reference.com:

> 2. the sum, total, count, or aggregate of a collection of units, or the like

Merriam-Webster:

> 1a.  (1) :  a sum of units :  total (2) :  complement 1b (3) :  an indefinite usually large total   (4) plural :  a numerous group :  many (5) :  a numerical preponderance

Therefore, here are some other, mostly synonymous phrasings:

> Many (philosophers) began to value reason.
>
> A group (of philosophers) began to value reason.
>
> A preponderance (of philosophers) began to value reason.

### A Skeptical Number

So the subject of the sentence being modified is *not* "philosophers", it's "a number". It might be more useful to look at it as "a number of philosophers", but the phrase specifying what we have a number of may not always be present in the sentence. It could be from context:

> At this time there were a great many philosophers in Athens. Skeptical of the abilities of prophets to tell the future, a significant number began to value reason over revealed truths.

So yes, 'skeptical' *can* modify number, because "a number" is a group of things, and the things in the group can be skeptical.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of "number" as "group" or "set."

You're right that skeptical modifies number, but in this case the phrase "of philosophers" defines the number as a set of people, which can be skeptical.