# A minority has or a minority have?

Tags: grammaticality

I wrote:

> a minority of pairs has (...)

A native speaker corrected this with:

> a minority of pairs have (...)

Which one is correct?  I thought it should be the former, because minority is singular.  But English is funny sometimes with collective nouns.  What is the case here?

Comment: Is there a BrE/AmE difference here? AmE speaker here, and I would say "a minority of pairs has", but then I also say "Microsoft has" whereas I think a BrE speaker would say "Microsoft have".

Comment: "Minority" is being used here as a [*quantificational noun*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31841/32), so you've got some wiggle room in deciding which noun governs the verb.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'minority' to mean 'a small number of' which can mean more than one.  A similar sentence to illustrate this would be:

> A **small number** of pairs **have**

If you meant a single pair and want to use 'has', you should sign-post this explicitly e.g.

> A pair has *or* A single pair **has**

Comment: In context it is certainly more than one.  I realise the grammar for "a small number" is the same, but why is it "have"; "number" is singular?

Comment: According to OALD (AE and BE),  only a small minority of students is/are interested in politics these days.  However, The Free DIctionary says we must use the plural form of a verb  after the plural noun.

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/minority?q=minority

Comment: Actually,  a minority doesn't mean a small number . It means the smaller numbered group of two or more groups. A minority population can still have millions of members.