# Is "there's a myriad of combinations" grammatically acceptable?

Tags: grammar

(I don't know if this is the right place to ask this; if it's not please let me know.)

So I'm a PA & I’ve been having an argument with my boss over the following:

I was under the impression that it is perfectly acceptable, although informal, to say: “**There's** *a myriad of possible combinations*” but he insists that 
“There are *a myriad of possible combinations*” is the only correct way to say it.

We both are non-native English speakers. Could you help us out?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This quesiton fits better on the [English site](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think you will find the answer to your question [at this page on EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202768/there-is-the-people-vs-there-are-the-people/202783#202783)

Comment: In modern English it's probably best to drop the *of* there. The answer is that you are right and your boss is wrong!

Comment: Agreed this question should be asked on ELU or ELL. This site, Linguistics, is for questions which apply to any language, or to language-specific questions which don't already have sites dedicated to them (like, I dunno, Tamil). Having said that: if your boss subscribes to the Classic Greek definition that *a myriad* is exactly 10,000, sure, it's *are*. But if he's a speaker of contemporary English, where *a myriad* means *a bunch*, and is a mass noun, uncountable, then go with *is* (but drop the *of*, as Acaucaria advises).

Comment: The theoretical issue here is that contracted or otherwise reified lexical items often lose affordances. The _is_ in _There's_ is no longer available for number agreement, for instance, just like the _leaf_ in _Toronto Maple Leafs_ no longer has an irregular plural _leaves_.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. As to your recommendation to drop the _of_: somehow I find it confusing.
Let's say I let the _of_ go. 
In this case a _myriad_-noun will become a _myriad_-adjective, right?
And I am having a really hard time using an article _a_ with a noun phrase, consisting of NP head in plural form "combinations" and determiner "myriad possible". 
Am I missing something or just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

"There are myriad" and "there are a myriad" are both correct, and in fact [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20are%20myriad%2Cthere%20are%20a%20myriad%2Cthere%20is%20myriad%2Cthere%20is%20a%20myriad%2Cthere%27s%20a%20myriad%2Cthere%27s%20a%20myriad&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) shows that both are far more common than the "there is" and "there's" variations.

Some weird logic has been used by some people here to suggest that "myriad" has to be  singular, even though everyone would say "There are a thousand".

(In British English, collective nouns are frequently treated as plural, but even American English regularly treats numerals and expressions like "a lot" as plural.)

"There are myriad combinations" (where "myriad" is an adjective) would probably be commoner than "there are a myriad of combinations", but both are correct.

"There is a myriad of combinations", with singular agreement, should probably be regarded as correct, too.  But even if it weren't, "There's" would still be acceptable colloquially, in the same way that "There's hundreds" or "There's five" is generally accepted colloquially, even though formally it should be "There are hundreds" and "There are five".  ("There're" is not often seen written down, though some people say it.)

Answer (score 1):

- The verb is *is* and the complement of *is* is *myriad* - which is a singular noun, not  *combinations.*
- You could not use an article if the *myriad* was plural
- *Myriad* would have to have an *s* on the end of it if it were plural.
- *Combinations* is part of the prepositional phrase *of possible combinations* which is modifying *myriad*.  That doesn't make *myriad* plural.  Prepositional phrases don't turn nouns into plural nouns
- Since *myriad* already means *many of*, saying *myriads* means *multiple instances of many of X* which is probably not what is meant.

---

So, I was saying that either of two below would be valid:

> There is a myriad of possible combinations
>
> There are myriad possible combinations

But ... @StoneyB brings up a very interesting and good point in the comment about "oblique" subjects in cases where it is described by *of X*.

In particular, from the [question cited](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31841/a-sentence-from-swans-peu-using-plural-are-and-not-singular-is/31848#31848) in the comment, this:

> Lots of work<sup>oblique</sup> is left to be done.

would sound wrong if said *Lots of work are left to be done*.  It looks like *lots* (plural) is the subject of the sentence but it doesn't work with a plural verb.

Though the equivalent structure with the example sentence's words does not work with *myriad* because *combinations* is countable (and you have to use *myriad* with a countable noun because it means *many of*, not *much*).

> Myriads of combinations is possible (sounds off to me)

In any event,  using one of the first two sentences above is definitely 100% correct, but I am not sure whether "There are a myriad of possible combinations" is 100% incorrect.

Comment: Mmm ... but see [this answer on ELU](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31848/32), which addresses what *CGEL* calls "number-transparent quantificational nouns" like *lots, a lot, a bunch".

Comment: You should provide an example with what you think is the ideal rectified sentence after your list of notes on the parts.

Comment: For what reason do you treat "a myriad" differently than "a thousand" or "a million", Lawrence?  [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myriad) lists "There *are* a myriad of possibilities." among its examples, which demonstrates that the word in this use is plural.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing, otherwise I would not be here searching out the answer! When you get down to the root meaning of the word, "myriad" originally meant "10,000", and was later morphed into simply meaning a lot. So the answer above relating to thousand or million is invalid. I know that it is acceptable to say, "There are 10,000 horses in the barns." but it is not acceptable to say, "There is 10,000 horses in the barns." So if we use the original meaning, it seems like myriad should always be plural, because it NEVER refers to a single unit of anything.